# Javascript Show/hide

Tags: javascript, menu, hide, show

I dont know whats the mistake:

```
<script>
                function craft()
    {
    document.getElementById(craft).style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById(smell).style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById(other).style.visibility="hidden";
    }

function smell()
{
document.getElementById(craft).style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById(smell).style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById(other).style.visibility="hidden";
}

function other()
{
document.getElementById(craft).style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById(smell).style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById(other).style.visibility="visible";
}
        </script>



    <a onclick ="craft()" href="#">Craft</a><br>
    <a onclick ="smell()" href="#">Smell</a><br>
    <a onclick ="other()" href="#">Other</a><br>
    <div id="craft" style="display: none;" >CraftCraftCraftCraftCraftCraftCraft</div><br>
      <div id="smell" style="display: none;" >SmellSmellSmellSmellSmellSmellSmell</div><br>
        <div id="other" style="display: none;" >OtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOther</div><br>
```

Im trying to make somethink like a menu. When i click Craft button, there will apear just the contain

I cant find the mistake...
I tryed the code in browser, but there apeared jut the links... Ans when i clicked them, nothing happend...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `'` around the IDs in `document.getElementById()`. For example:

```
document.getElementById('craft').style.visibility="visible";
```

Without them JavaScript will try to interpret `craft` as a variable (holding the value for the ID) and not as a string denoting the actual ID.

**EDIT**

After taking a second look, you do not use consistent properties to hide your `<div>`s:

At the start you hide them with `display: none;` and then try to make them shown by `visibility: visible;`. You have to be consistent here. Either use `display` or `visibility`. Both differ in what they actually do.

So either adjust your JavaScript to use `display` like this:

```
document.getElementById('craft').style.display = "block";
```

Or disable initially by using `visibility: hidden;` like this:

```
<div id="craft" style="visibility: hidden;" >CraftCraftCraftCraftCraftCraftCraft</div>
```

[*Working Example Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/F4AqB/)